# React MUI, How to append to a Masonry Image List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to use the [React MUI Masonry Image List](https://mui.com/components/image-list/#masonry-image-list) component with the [infintie scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component) component. They seem to work pretty great together.

However, the issue I'm having is appending to the Masonry image list. I successfully append new images, but the whole masonry moves jump and becomes jittery when new images are loaded.

I wonder if it's possible just to add the images to the bottom of the page without the whole thing spazzing out.

Here is a code the illustrates this, basically I just modified the Masonry image list demo:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import ImageList from '@mui/material/ImageList';
import ImageListItem from '@mui/material/ImageListItem';
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


export default function MasonryImageList() {

  const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const fetchMore = async (itemData) =>{
      await sleep(2000)
      setItems(prev_items => [...prev_items,...itemData])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMore(itemData);
  }, []);


  return (
    <Box id="scrolableDiv" sx={{ width: 800, height: 800, overflowY: 'scroll' }}>
      <ImageList variant="masonry" cols={3} gap={8}>
      <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={items.length}
          next={fetchMore(itemData)}
          hasMore={true}
          loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
          scrollableTarget= "scrolableDiv"
        >
        {items.map((item) => (
          <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
            <img
              src={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format`}
              srcSet={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`}
              alt={item.title}
              loading="lazy"
            />
          </ImageListItem>
          
        ))}
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </ImageList>
    </Box>
  );
}

const itemData = [
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549388604-817d15aa0110',
    title: 'Bed',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525097487452-6278ff080c31',
    title: 'Books',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523413651479-597eb2da0ad6',
    title: 'Sink',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563298723-dcfebaa392e3',
    title: 'Kitchen',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588436706487-9d55d73a39e3',
    title: 'Blinds',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574180045827-681f8a1a9622',
    title: 'Chairs',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530731141654-5993c3016c77',
    title: 'Laptop',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481277542470-605612bd2d61',
    title: 'Doors',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517487881594-2787fef5ebf7',
    title: 'Coffee',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516455207990-7a41ce80f7ee',
    title: 'Storage',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597262975002-c5c3b14bbd62',
    title: 'Candle',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519710164239-da123dc03ef4',
    title: 'Coffee table',
  },
];
```

If you see any glaring errors, please point them out, I've just started with React.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me, hoping someone comes up with a solution soon.

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this similar problem. What worked for me was to supply <img> with a minimum height value.

ie.

```
<img
  src={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format`}
  srcSet={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`}
  alt={item.title}
  loading="lazy"
  style={{ minHeight: 10 }}   //Added minHeight; 10 is just a sample value
/>
```

Since masonry lists depend on the height of the element, minHeight serves as a placeholder value while the img has not yet loaded.